# remove keywords magento and hide description when empty

Tags: magento, keyword

I would like to delete all keywords meta tags from my magento store and hide all the discrypion tags when empty

Is this possible by local.xml ? i try the following but it didn't work:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>meta</type>
            <name>keywords</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
M2 If you want to remove all the meta tag completely, you can achieve this by plugin. I have created a module for this hope this will help:
```

Create Vendor/RemoveMetaTag/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_RemoveMetaTag',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create Vendor/RemoveMetaTag/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_RemoveMetaTag" />
</config>
```

Create Vendor/RemoveMetaTag/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="removeMetaTag" type="Vendor\RemoveMetaTag\Plugin\PageConfig\RemoveMetaTag" sortOrder="1000"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then lastly create you plugin in

```
Vendor/RemoveMetaTag/Plugin/PageConfig/RemoveMetaKeywords.php

<?php
namespace Vtn\RemoveMetaTag\Plugin\PageConfig;

class RemoveMetaTag {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {        
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetMetadata($subject, array $metaData) {
        $pathInfo = $this->request->getPathInfo();
        $pageId = str_replace("/cms/page/view/page_id/","",$pathInfo);

        if ($pageId == "your_page_id") {
            return [];
        }
        return $metaData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not copying **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml** to:

**app/design/frontend//default/template/page/html/head.phtml** and do:

1. Remove the following line:

   ```
     <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
   ```
2. Change the following line:

   ```
       <meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
   ```

   into

   ```
       <?php if (!empty($this->getDescription())) :?>
          <meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
       <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Comment: I try to work with a local.xml as mutch as possible. But this work's excelent as well....  Thanks :o)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible via layout.xml, you have to copy the template file page/html/head.phtml to your theme and make changes as @Sander Pham suggested